# Manually Triggering drillup event, highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am working on drilldown/up chart of highchart.. i was able to trigger drill down event on a point click from outside highchart through:

```
chart.series[0].data[0].firePointEvent('click', event);
```

but i can't find any event which would trigger on the back button of the chart. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yw4Vh/109/)
I want to programatically trigger click event on "Back to Overview" event. Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you can just call `drillUp()` function on your chart like this:

```
$('#drillUp').click(function() {
    if (chart.drilldownLevels.length > 0) {
        chart.drillUp();
    }
});
```

You need to check that `chart.drilldownLevels` array contains elements before calling this function. See updated [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yw4Vh/113/).

Comment: Lost 3 hours searching this info, this was very helpful.

Comment: After an hour of trying to get event listeners on the back button to fire, this solved the issue. I still wonder why I can't attach event listeners to the drill up button. Anybody else had issues here?